# Android In App Billing and storing Managed Purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Im looking at porting a popular WP7 game of mine to Android.  What I would like to do is offer it as free, but after about 5 minutes of play time the only option the downloader would have is an in app purchase to fully unlock the game.  However, I see that the official Android SDK for IAB in the context of Managed Purchases has a "Restore_Transactions" available, but it doesn't say I can use this on each launch of the game. http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

So, the question is, how/where/what format do I store the fact that the user unlocked the game without calling "Restore_Transactions" on every game launch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the developer, you are responsible for restoring purchased transactions of the managed purchase type. The sample Dungeons application queries for managed user purchases on app start. I do not believe network access is required to query the market for in-app purchases, as it queries the internal market db for auth.

For more info, find this code in `Dungeons.java`

```
.....

/**
 * Reads the set of purchased items from the database in a background thread
 * and then adds those items to the set of owned items in the main UI
 * thread.
 */
private void doInitializeOwnedItems() {

.....
```

and fully read the following: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: Interesting that this isn't a network call and just an internal db call.

Comment: You "do not believe"?  This is why I asked, if it uses the internal market db for authorization then great, problem solved, and there is no issue with calling restore_transaction on every app start.  Otherwise, I couldn't use that in my use case because then offline players of the game couldn't play the fully unlocked game.  Does anyone have confirmation or documentation (other than an ambiguous code comment) that this uses the internal market db?  If so, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: You could just test it :-) Turn the net off on your emulator and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

In your publisher page of your android market. you can set the in app purchase item to 'managed purchase'. This means the android market will keep a record that the user has bought this item.

Therefore if you query the android market on loadup it will return your "RESTORE_TRANSACTION" state and you know that the user has purchased this item.

As your asking how do you **not** do this:

You could store it in a database on the phone (easily hackable by a rooted phone).

You could store it encrypted in a database in multiple tables on the phone (less hackable, will be lost if the user uninstall's).

You could store a user reference on your phone with the database stored on a secure server of your own (something like the IMEI number concat'd with the install date and a SecureRandom().nextLong()).

or

As you said you don't want to do, you could store the original purchase then query the InApp billing service.

Quoted from the google doc:

> If you have a remote server, we recommend that you store purchase information on your server instead of in a local database on a device

Further reading:
[InApp Security & Design](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html)

Comment: No, I dont want to store it on the phone for the reasons you mentioned but am not aware that Restore_Transaction requires a network connection in order to get a response.